# Forward fill to a specific datetime index - if the datetime index occurs in other list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, overwrite

I'm trying to overwrite pre calculated weights in a df for products through a datetime index. My challenge is to only overwrite to a certain date (listed in another df) and then doing it again . Example of data :

```
data = {'Product 1 Weight':['0', '.15', '.19', '.2','.21','.25','.252','.255'],
    'Product 2 Weight':['0', '0', '0', '0','0','0','0','0'],
    'Product 3 Weight':['0', '0', '0', '0','0','.5','.551','.561']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2020-04-01',
                            '2020-04-02',
                            '2020-04-03',
                            '2020-04-06',
                            '2020-04-07',
                            '2020-04-08',
                            '2020-04-09',
                            '2020-04-10'])

rebalances= pd.DataFrame({'Rebalance':['2020-04-02',
                                   '2020-04-08',
                                   '2020-04-10']})
```

In this example I'd like to overwrite the values of all the Products from 2020-04-02 to 2020-04-07 with the values from 2020-04-02. I'd then like to overwrite the values of all the products from 2020-04-08 to 2020-04-09 with the values from 2020-04-08 and so on. The rebalances df will give me the dates to stop the overwrite and start another one. My desired final output would therefore look like :

```
data = {'Product 1 Weight':['0', '.15', '.15', '.15','.15','.25','.25','.255'],
    'Product 2 Weight':['0', '0', '0', '0','0','0','0','0'],
    'Product 3 Weight':['0', '0', '0', '0','0','.5','.5','.561']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2020-04-01',
                            '2020-04-02',
                            '2020-04-03',
                            '2020-04-06',
                            '2020-04-07',
                            '2020-04-08',
                            '2020-04-09',
                            '2020-04-10'])
```

Might seem completely random but would be great for my current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `mask` the values in `Product` like columns where the corresponding `index` is not present in `Rebalance` column then `ffill` to forward fill and overwrite the masked values.

```
m = df.index.to_series().isin(rebalances['Rebalance'])
out = df.mask(~m).ffill().fillna(df)
```

---

```
>>> out

           Product 1 Weight Product 2 Weight Product 3 Weight
2020-04-01                0                0                0
2020-04-02              .15                0                0
2020-04-03              .15                0                0
2020-04-06              .15                0                0
2020-04-07              .15                0                0
2020-04-08              .25                0               .5
2020-04-09              .25                0               .5
2020-04-10             .255                0             .561
```